# Current section header for article class

Tags: header-footer

In the `article` class, is there  a way to obtain, in each page, the header displaying the name of the section with the number of the page? I need the same visualization like the `book` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\let\MakeUppercase=\relax
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
Foo
\newpage
\section{Bar}
Bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: in this way the header is written with capital letters. If I want it in lowercase text?

Comment: @Galoisfan: See my update above.